# swagger-codegen custom generator ClassNotFound

Tags: swagger

I'm writing a custom generator for swagger-codegen. When I attempt to run the generator with

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i path/to/swagger.json -l com.my.company.codegen.MyGenerator -o outputlocation
```

it fails with

```
Can't load config class with name com.my.company.codegen.MyGenerator

... list of built-in generators...

    at io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:31)
    at io.swagger.codegen.config.CodegenConfigurator.toClientOptInput(CodegenConfigurator.java:286)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:186)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.company.codegen.MyGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:29)
    ... 3 more
```

I'm not having trouble with any of the built-in generators.

What I did to get here (following the readme):

1. cloned the project
2. `mvn package`
3. `java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar meta -o output/myLibrary -n myGenerator -p com.my.company.codegen`
4. and then the above code

I also tried running `mvn package` again after making my custom generator (which did not make a .jar file anywhere I could find), and tried creating the .jar file myself. Got the same error.

Also FYI, my confusion was definitely increased by some apparent documentation inconsistencies: expected location for my module differs between [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#making-your-own-codegen-modules) and the `classname` expected [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#customizing-the-generator) (end of that section). Also, the command for [making your own module](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/README.md#making-your-own-codegen-modules) specifies `modules/swagger-codegen-distribution...` when I believe it should specify `modules/swagger-codegen-cli...`. And the guidance in the project readme doesn't seem very congruent with the custom module readme that is generated [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/codegen/README.mustache).

I don't normally work with Java, so apologies if I'm just missing something super obvious. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a bunch of things / internetting, here is what worked:

`java -cp output/myLibrary/target/myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i path/to/swagger.json -l com.my.company.codegen.MyCustomCodegenGenerator -o outputlocation`

Here are the steps I had to take start to finish to create a custom generator:

1. `git clone` from source
2. `cd swagger-codegen`
3. `mvn package`
4. `java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar meta -o output/myLibrary -n myCustomCodegen -p com.my.company.codegen`. This will create `output/myLibrary` and subdirectories, where you should find `myCustomCodegenGenerator.java` ("Generator" is appended to the class name you specify in the command). You should also be able to find the mustache templates within the resources subdirectory.
5. Make whatever changes you want to `myCustomCodegenGenerator.java` and the templates.
6. `cd output/myLibrary`
7. `mvn package`
8. `cd ../..`
9. Now generate your custom library: `java -cp output/myLibrary/target/myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i path/to/swagger.json -l com.my.company.codegen.MyCustomCodegenGenerator -o outputlocation` (building in step 7 should have generated `target/myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar` for you)

Notes:

- Obviously the `cd`ing is based on where I put things, just wanted to be clear on relatively where I was when running commands
- If you are just using the default generated base class for your generator (instead of subclassing an existing language), you will get an exception `FileNotFound` for `myCustomCodegen/myFile.mustache` -- it's from [this optional block](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/2ea3816e652e53a5138f6a9d4c9fd92146a0c0be/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/codegen/generatorClass.mustache#L106) which you can just comment out of your custom generator class.

  - Remember to `mvn package` your custom module when you make changes

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include your custom library in the java command.  For example:

```
java -cp path/to/your/jar.com:modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar \
   -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar \
   {args}
```

Comment: Sorry for slow response, was still trying to work through it. See my own accepted answer for the steps I took. Issue with above was that `-cp` is ignored in conjunction with `-jar`. Answer is bit of an amalgamation between your suggestion and the generated readme. Looks like y'all were really quick about updating the main readme, would be great if you could update [generated readme](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/2ea3816e652e53a5138f6a9d4c9fd92146a0c0be/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/codegen/README.mustache#L49) too!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are attempting to create a generator in Windows and run it from PowerShell, I had to modify @baylee's steps as follows:

3. `mvn install`

and

9. `java -cp 'output/myLibrary/target/myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar;modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar' io.swagger.codegen.Codegen -i path/to/swagger.json -l my-language -o outputlocation`